# How to call Firebase onRequest Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the following addEventToCalendar cloud function :

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const calendar = google.calendar("v3");
//const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const googleCredentials = require("./credentials.json");
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

const ERROR_RESPONSE = {
  status: "500",
  message: "There was an error adding an event to your Google calendar",
};
const TIME_ZONE = "EST";

const addEvent = (event, auth) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    calendar.events.insert(
      {
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: "primary",
        resource: {
          summary: event.eventName,
          description: event.description,
          start: {
            dateTime: event.startTime,
            timeZone: TIME_ZONE,
          },
          end: {
            dateTime: event.endTime,
            timeZone: TIME_ZONE,
          },
        },
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Rejecting because of error");
          reject(err);
        }
        console.log("Request successful");
        resolve(res.data);
      }
    );
  });
}




exports.addEventToCalendar = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const eventData = {
    eventName: request.body.eventName,
    description: request.body.description,
    startTime: request.body.startTime,
    endTime: request.body.endTime,
  };
  console.log("Event Data: ", eventData);
  const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2(
    googleCredentials.web.client_id,
    googleCredentials.web.client_secret,
    googleCredentials.web.redirect_uris[0]
  );

  oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: googleCredentials.refresh_token,
  });

  addEvent(eventData, oAuth2Client)
    .then((data) => {
      response.status(200).send(data);
      return;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error adding event: " + err.message);
      response.status(500).send(ERROR_RESPONSE);
      return;
    });
});
```

URL looks like this : http://localhost:5001/prototype-dev-fadd5/us-central1/addEventToCalendar

How do I call this by passing the following data?

```
     {
        "eventName": "Firebase Event",
        "description": "This is a sample description",
        "startTime": "2018-12-01T10:00:00",
        "endTime": "2018-12-01T13:00:00"
      )
```

When I say call, it implies 2 things:

1. Call from a browser just to test it.
2. Call it from another firebase cloud function which runs on a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

To call it from a browser, you can call it using XHR:

```js
const data = {
  eventName: 'Firebase Event',
  description: 'This is a sample description',
  startTime: '2018-12-01T10:00:00',
  endTime: '2018-12-01T13:00:00' 
}

fetch('http://localhost:5001/prototype-dev-fadd5/us-central1/addEventToCalendar', { 
  method: 'POST', 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => {
  // ...
}).catch(error => {
  // ...
});
```

To call it from another Cloud Function, I'd suggest exporting the `addEvent` function so you can import and use it elsewhere.

I'd also move the creation of the `oAuth2Client` object over to the `addEvent()` function so that you don't have to create an oAuth client before calling the `addEvent()` function.

If you can't re-use the `addEvent()` function because the two Cloud Functions live in separate projects and you can't share code between them, I'd call the function through XHR using a tool like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

Answer (score 0):

I know the tutorial you are using.

There are two good ways to test it:

1. Google Cloud Function Console, Testing tab
2. Postman

And for using it, I can think of 3 good ways to actually use it.

1. fetch Javascript from the frontend
2. Callable Firebase Functions from the frontend
3. export import to use from the backend.

## Testing - Google Cloud Functions Console.

https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/

[image]

## Testing - Postman

To test you can also use Postman.

Create a POST request with the URL of your function.
Then set the body to `raw`, with the type set to `JSON`. Once that is all setup, hit send and the response will show up if you did everything correctly.

See this image on where to click in Postman.
[image]

## Using - fetch

Fetch provides a

> global fetch() method that provides an easy, logical way to fetch
> resources asynchronously across the network.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

And luckily, Postman will write the fetch code for you.
Click on the Code tab, and select Javascript - Fetch from the dropdown.
[image]

## Using - Callable Functions

Callable Functions are functions you can call directly from your Javascript on the front end. They are explained here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Biggest difference is instead of using

```
functions.https.onRequest
```

in your function declaration, you use:

```
functions.https.onCall
```

## Using - export to use in Node.js on your server

If you want to be able to call a function directly on your Node.js server, aka your Firebase functions, if the function is in the same file, you call it like any other javascript file.

```
function normalFunction() {
  //do work
  return data;
}

exports.addEventToCalendar = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  let data = normalFunction();
  response.send(data);
}
```

You can put whatever you want in the normalFunction and call it where ever you want. Just make sure to use a promise, or await if it is doing something on a server etc.

If you want to use `normalFunction` from a different file, you would need to use `export`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Firebase has a good doc on how you can organize multiple files here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions

[image]